# Failure with Spring 4 + Java 8 when executing JUnit 4 test: Failed to read candidate component class

Tags: macos, java-8, junit4, spring-4

I'm facing a problem which I can't solve after doing some research around:

When I run my JUnit4 test, I get error:

> ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught
>   exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1e0b4072]
>   to prepare test instance [com.foo.bar.ClassUnderTest@791f145a]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to read candidate component class: file
>   [/Users/foouser/git/projectName/target/classes/foo/bar/ProblematicClass.class];
>   nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   51966     at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(Unknown Source)
>     at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
>     ... 46 more

I checked for any Spring compatibility issue with 'mvn dependency:tree' and everything seems to be fine, as I'm using Spring 4 (suitable for Java 8):

```
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Test is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import foo.bar.ProblematicClass;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml"})
public class ClassTest {

    @Autowired
    ProblematicClass problematicClass;

    @Test
    public void testGetInstance() {

        Assert.assertNotNull(problematicClass);

    }

}
```

I have several methods which uses Java 8 lambda features internally in the problematic class, and it seems like Spring wouldn't be suittable for resolving the code correctly, because when I comment that code my test runs perfectly, but for whatever reason, when I uncomment and test is running, that code raises the error.

I configured the JRE System Library to be JavaSE-1.8 compatible:

[image: Java 8 configuration]

Also, my JAVA_HOME is pointing to my Java 8 SDK installation:

[image: JavaHome]

Hope you may help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.